# Measuring the deviation of data distributed in a large range from a model

Tags: modeling, error

I have some data in the range $10^{-5} \sim 1$ and I want to see if the model that I have for this data is valid or not. My problem is that, given the range where my data is distributed, if I calculate the [RMSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) of my data with respect to the model the only important values (for the calculations) are those that are close to 1 (because a difference here has a huge impact in the value that I would obtain for the RMSD) and it is not important what happens for values between $10^{-3}$ and $10^{-5}$ provided that the model is *decent* in that region (because this error would be small anyway and it doesn't affect the RMSD that much).

This means that the model could be two orders of magnitude apart from the data in the small values range and it wouldn't be noticeable when looking at the RMSD.

I want to be able to somehow measure the precision of the model both in the large value and the small value range. If I use the RMSD it is not possible because deviations from the model in the large value range contribute a lot more than deviations in the small value range.

Let me give you an example to make it clearer: let's consider that I have only two values $1$ and $10^{-5}$ and that my model predicts $1$ and $10^{-3}$. Then the RMSD would be $0.02$ which is a very small value even though the model is not precise at all for one of the values. I would like to be able to quantify that the model is not precise in this small values region.

How can I estimate the deviation of the data from the model taking this into account?

P.S. The model that I have is some distribution with parameters that I have obtained fitting them to the data.

Comment: You seem to be asking for two completely different things: (1) "it is not important what happens for values between $10^{−3}$ and $10^{−5}$" yet (2) "I would like the model to be also precise for small values."  Could you clarify what you need, preferably a little more quantitatively and less abstractly?

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I wanted to say something different. For the calculation the only important values are those close to 1 because if the model is not precise here it will give a huge contribution to the RMSD but if it is not precise for small values it is not going to change the RMSD a lot. So I am interested in a way of being able to see how precise it is for small and large values at the same time. I will edit the question now to reflect in. Thanks.

Comment: @whuber I have just edited the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear, and for a good answer some context would be helpful. Can you provide it? What are you modeling, what does your variables represent, can you actually state your model? --- with formulas?

Waiting for that, it sounds you are coping with [heteroskedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity), with lower variance around the smaller (close to zero) values. Then you might want to use some weighted analysis, measuring error by something like [relative variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_dispersion), or use a log transform on the data. We cannot tell you without more context.